# Simple jQuery ".replace()" string not working with RegEx

Tags: jquery

I trying to use `.replace()` to change everything between the two last slashes of this URL with "w270" but nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong? **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wbqez42c/)**

```
<div class="post-outer">
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9h_QVOCOX1w/XvnuC9SucSI/AAAAAAAABJo/roFOy4Tgs64wSDtI9-dC9WyglJJdPz3fACK4BGAsYHg/w100/image.png"/>
</div>

// The RegEx target everything between the two last slashes
    $('.post-outer img').attr('src').replace(/[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/]*$)/, 'w270');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`attr(attributeName, function)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) simplifies this since it exposes current value in the callback and will also loop over all matching selectors and perform same task on each instance

```js
$('.post-outer img').attr('src', (_, curr) => curr.replace(/[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/]*$)/, 'w270'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-outer">
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9h_QVOCOX1w/XvnuC9SucSI/AAAAAAAABJo/roFOy4Tgs64wSDtI9-dC9WyglJJdPz3fACK4BGAsYHg/w100/image.png"/>
</div>
<div class="post-outer">
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9h_QVOCOX1w/XvnuC9SucSI/AAAAAAAABJo/roFOy4Tgs64wSDtI9-dC9WyglJJdPz3fACK4BGAsYHg/w100/image.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks :) Can you tell me what `(_, curr) =>` does? Googled it and couldn't find much about it.

Comment: It's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Almost the same as `function(_,curr){/* do stuff*/}))`. The `_` is simply a placeholder argument and is the index value of the collection which is not needed in this case ... `curr` is the current attribute value

Answer (score 3):

Replace returns a new string, it does not modify the original, you will need to assign the result back to the attribute.

```js
const img = $('.post-outer img');
const url = img.attr('src').replace(/[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/]*$)/, 'w270');
img.attr('src', url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-outer">
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9h_QVOCOX1w/XvnuC9SucSI/AAAAAAAABJo/roFOy4Tgs64wSDtI9-dC9WyglJJdPz3fACK4BGAsYHg/w100/image.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: It works partially. I should mentioned that I have several <div class="post-outer"> within a <div class="post-list"> parent. Your code and Majed Badawi code above repeat the first .post-outer img on all following .post-outer img. I updated my fiddle with your code, can you take a look? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ek4cy23h/)

Comment: You need to make your selector target the image you want to update. '.post-outer img' will target all images that are children of an element with the class 'post-outer'. `$('.post-outer:first img')` will target the first post. You need to explain what you want to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
let url = $('.post-outer img').attr('src');
$($('.post-outer img')[0]).attr('src', url.replace(/[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/]*$)/, 'w270'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-outer">
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9h_QVOCOX1w/XvnuC9SucSI/AAAAAAAABJo/roFOy4Tgs64wSDtI9-dC9WyglJJdPz3fACK4BGAsYHg/w100/image.png"/>
</div>
<div class="post-outer">
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9h_QVOCOX1w/XvnuC9SucSI/AAAAAAAABJo/roFOy4Tgs64wSDtI9-dC9WyglJJdPz3fACK4BGAsYHg/w100/image.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: It works partially. I should mentioned that I have several <div class="post-outer"> within a <div class="post-list"> parent. Your code and Adrian Brand code below repeat the first .post-outer img on all following .post-outer img. I updated my fiddle with Adrian code, can you take a look? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ek4cy23h/)

Comment: @KimSantos just change the ``src`` for the first child as above

Comment: Majed but `[0]` is applying the replace only in the first `<div class="post-outer"><img/></div>` from a `<div class="post-list">` parent with 27 `<div class="post-outer"><img/></div>`. Any other suggestion?

Comment: If you could take a look at my [website homepage](https://andre.mototaxi.club/) you'll see that only the first image is getting the RegEx applied with your edited code. Your first code repeat this first image on all the other images.

Comment: I mean what is missing from the solution? Don't you want to apply the ``replace`` to the first one only?

Comment: Thanks Majed, fixed it now :) The RegEx replaces a low-res image link to a high-res image link, but your updated code was replacing only the first image. I updated the website with @charlietfl code and now it's working like it supposed to be. Take a look again to understand what was my goal.